# How to Find File Path of Class Declaration in a Source Generator

Tags: c#, .net, sourcegenerators

Title pretty much explains it. I am writing a source generator and would like to know how to find the file path of a given `ClassDeclarationSyntax` node. Here is an example of how I'd like to be able to use it.

```
IEnumerable<SyntaxNode> allNodes = compilation.SyntaxTrees.SelectMany(s => s.GetRoot().DescendantNodes());
IEnumerable<ClassDeclarationSyntax> allClasses = allNodes.Where(d => d.IsKind(SyntaxKind.ClassDeclaration))
                                                         .OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>();
IEnumerable<string> filePaths = allClasses.Select(x=> x.GetFilePath());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following code to get the containing file path:

```cs
SyntaxNode node = ...;
_ = node.SyntaxTree.FilePath;
_ = node.GetLocation().SourceTree?.FilePath // SourceTree can be null
```

Comment: Why does my node witch is a ClassDeclarationSyntax have an empty FilePath?

Answer (score 0):

For the ones looking to make this work in unit tests. When creating a SyntaxTree manually, you need to also fill the path parameter.

```cs
[Fact]
public Task ExecGenerator()
{
    var generator = new MyGenerator();
    // Create the driver that will control the generation, passing in our generator
    GeneratorDriver driver = CSharpGeneratorDriver.Create(generator);

    // Run the generation pass
    // (Note: the generator driver itself is immutable, and all calls return an updated version of the driver that you should use for subsequent calls)
    var compilation = CreateCompilation("MyFile.cs");
    return driver.RunGenerators(compilation);
}

private static Compilation CreateCompilation(string filePath)
{
    var source = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

    return CSharpCompilation.Create(
        assemblyName: "tests",
        syntaxTrees: new[] { CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(source, path: filePath) },
        references: new[]
        {
            MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location)
        });
}
```

Then in your generator, you can use:

```cs
syntaxNode.SyntaxTree.FilePath
```